# Creating an arithmetic sequence that increases by a number other than 1 in Wolfram|Alpha

Tags: wolfram-alpha

Say I want to find numbers between 1 and 10, but I want the sequence to increase by .1, how would I accomplish this?

Comment: Better suited to http://mathematica.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @lhf I'm a bit unfamiliar with the different sites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`range[1, 10, 0.1]`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=range%5B1,+10,+0.1%5D)

> {1., 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2., 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9, 3., 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 4., 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4, 4.5, 4.6, 4.7, 4.8, 4.9, 5., 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 5.5, 5.6, 5.7, 5.8, 5.9, 6., 6.1, 6.2, 6.3, 6.4, 6.5, 6.6, 6.7, 6.8, 6.9, 7., 7.1, 7.2, 7.3, 7.4, 7.5, 7.6, 7.7, 7.8, 7.9, 8., 8.1, 8.2, 8.3, 8.4, 8.5, 8.6, 8.7, 8.8, 8.9, 9., 9.1, 9.2, 9.3, 9.4, 9.5, 9.6, 9.7, 9.8, 9.9, 10.}

---

[ *EDIT* ]   Following OP's comment, I realized that [`1...10 step size .1`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1...10+step+size+.1) returns the same range.

Comment: I was using {0...n*10}/10

Comment: @script8man Thanks for the tip, see the new edit.